# Tinymce getting back just text

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have some custom validation for my forms on my tinymce textarea. My problem lies there unfortunately. I'm limiting the text entered to 500 characters and below the box I have a 'counter' that counts down the characters they have until it's too long.

I have a keyup function working, but I'm having trouble grabbing the plain text from the text area.

I've already tried

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
```

and

```
tinymce.get('wChal').getContent()
```

but those grab everything including the html, and it's really not fair for the user if it's also counting the invisible html.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers, I ended up doing something like this.

```
var con = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
var len = con.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;
```